# Parsing CSV with a RegEx in java - escape double quote within cell

Tags: java, regex, csv

I am looking for a java regex which will escape the doublequote within an excel cell.

I have followed this example but need another change in the regular expression to make it work for escaping doublequote within one of the cells.

[Parsing CSV input with a RegEx in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441556/parsing-csv-input-with-a-regex-in-java)

```
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)");
```

Example Data:

> "A,B"***,***"2" size"***,***"text1,text2, text3"

The regex from above fails at `2"`.

I want the output to be as below .Doesn't matter if the outer double quotes are there or not.

"A,B"
"2" size"
"text1,text2, text3"

Comment: Well, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: Why on earth would you parse csv with RegEx? I could see using RegEx on individual tokens once you've gotten those through conventional means but parsing the whole csv with RegEx is just a terrible idea. If I were conducting a code review on this I would tell you to rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: Why are you doing it with regex, instead of something like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) ?

Comment: @jlordo I don't have an option of using third party libraries. This regex was working fine until we came across data that may have a double quote within a cell data

Comment: Is _no third party libraries_ part of the homework or corporate requirement?

Comment: Do you wanna do this with Regex or are you accepting better sollutions?

Comment: Your input data is ambiguous, it is impossible to design either a regex or CSV solution that can properly handle all cases if you use double quotes as a delimiter, and also can include unescaped double quotes within fields.  For example `"foo","bar"` could be the fields `foo` and `bar`, or it could be one field with the contents `foo","bar`.

Comment: @F.J exactly what I want to say. there could be comma, double quote in content. so I could consider that the whole string (in OPs example) is just one field.

Comment: @rcdmk I can accept better solutions too

Comment: @F.J Is there any other solution that you can advise other than regex? The second field is a size field and the inch representation is what is causing this kind of data. 2"=2 inches

Comment: @user1864665 You need to work on whatever is generating that data, so that any double quotes within fields are escaped.  Your data should really look something like this: `"A,B","2\" size","text1,text2, text3"`.  If you can get it to that point, then CSV is your best bet and regex would be possible (but complicated).

Answer (score 0):

while I agree, that using regex for parsing a CVS is not really the best way, a slightly better pattern is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\"([^\"]*)\",|,\"([^\"]*)\",|,\"([^\"]*)\"$|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)");
```

This will terminate a cell value only after quote and comma, or start it after a command and a quote.

Comment: Thanks for the regex. Actually when the csv is opened in excel and saved back with modified data, double quotes surrounding a cell are gone. It preserves the double quotes if the cell has a comma within. So, in that case, my data is becoming, "A,B",2" size,"text1,text2, text3",text4,text5,"text6,text7" (I added three more columns to better understand).

Comment: What about double quote inside the text? Are these escaped in any way?

Comment: No, a double quote within a cell is not escaped. :(

Comment: I can have the double quote escaped with another double quote. For example, 2" will be 2"". How should I change the regex from my original post to ignore the escaped double quotes within a cell?

Comment: Your pattern may match a certain string, but cannot change it. So, the double quote removing should be done after matching. Please accept this whole answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

well as F.J commented, the input data is ambiguous. But for your example input, you could try

- `string.split("\",\"")` method to get a `String[]`. 
  after this, you got an array with 3 elements:

> ```
> [
> "A,B, 
> 2" size, 
> text1,text2, text3"
> ]
> ```

- remove the first character (which is double quote) of the first element of the array
- remove the last character (which is double quote) of the last element of the array