# java: csv...do I need a library?

Tags: java, csv

Do I need a library if I only need to make csv formatted file. I don't need reading and parsing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [csv api for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. And even reading/parsing can be easily done with a plain JRE.

CSV is a plain (ascii-)text format with only a few rules:

- rows (objects) are separated with a `\n`
- columns (fields, attributes) are spearated with a delimiter char (usually a comma, but define whatever you need)
- row and column delimiters must not be part of the field values

Comment: At least I've decided not to use any libraries)

Comment: That is so bad. Of course you are right. But why does everyone have to implement this manually? Why isn't there just a simple class in the Java collections or io API that does this?? I'm sick of having to think of escaping `";", ",", "\t", "\""` and all that again and again... :-(

Comment: @Lukas Eder - why don't you just implement your own private toolbox that has, amongst other stuff, some static helper methods for csv files ;-)

Comment: Well I do. Time and again ;-)

Comment: Don't forget platform-specific line terminators (*N.B.* fields can contain line terminators), and quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a really trivial part of your application and you're absolutely sure you won't ever need to parse a CSV file, you need a CSV-serialization library.

I have tried [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#what-is-opencsv) and I'm pretty happy using it. Of course you can write your own class to handle this serialization, but a library always comes with more features at the expense of an extra dependency...