# Generate CSV file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Can someone point me to some good tutorials for generating a resultset into a CSV or even Excel file?

I'm using j2ee, with Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, why are you dealing with raw ResultSets at all?

Comment: the best advice for java users would be "the new line is \n\r , not \n"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a utility that does CSV reading and writing:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

> can someone point me to some good tutorials for generating a resultset into a csv

It's extremely straightforward to roll your own — just make sure to use [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html). Or, [use a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java).

> or even excel file.

You'll want to use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use opencsv 2.2.jar

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
     // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
     String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
     writer.writeNext(entries);
    writer.close();