# Which apache commons CSV parser to use? SOLR CSV or commons CSV? Are they both the same?

Tags: java, open-source, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [csv api for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

There doesn't seem to any dev on **[commons-csv](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/index.html)** and **[solr-commons-csv](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-commons-csv)** mentions it is specifically intended for [apache-solr/lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

What is the preferred CSV parser you use? Should I just go with one of them, this is just CSV nothing complex.

Comment: I'm fine with closing it. But I was more asking about the difference between two apache commons implementations. I will try asking that in the mail lists then :)