# Signal character for file reading?

Tags: file-io

I am writing a simple Java applet for my friend.  Is there a character I can use that will never be practically used from the keyboard or almost never when taking notes as a signal?  I need to record a name, and then a note for that name.  But the note may have newlines so I cannot just use newlines here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could escape any newlines in the note if you want to use newlines as a delimiter. What would be more sensible, though, would be to just use a well-defined, lightweight file format that already exists, like [CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java).

If you really want to go rogue and bash together your own format, though, the traditional choice is [`NUL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), a.k.a. `\0` or `\u0000`.