# csv parser reading headers

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I'm working on a csv parser, I want to read headers and the rest of the csv file separately.
Here is my code to read csv.

The current code reads everything in the csv file, but I need to read headers separate.
please help me regarding this.

```
public class csv {

private void csvRead(File file)
{
    try
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));
    String strLine = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    File cfile=new File("csv.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cfile));
    int tokenNumber = 0;

    while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
            st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {

                    tokenNumber++;
                    writer.write(tokenNumber+"  "+ st.nextToken());
                    writer.newLine();
            }


            tokenNumber = 0;
            writer.flush();
    }
}

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to separate the reading of the headers from the rest of the file, then have a method that just handles the first line, and another method that handles all other lines in the file.

Answer (score 8):

We have withHeader() method available in CSVFormat. If you use this option then you will be able to read the file using headers.

```java
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.newFormat(',').withHeader();
Map<String, Integer> headerMap = dataCSVParser.getHeaderMap();
```

will give you all headers.

```
public class CSVFileReaderEx {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        readFile();
    }

    public static void readFile(){
         List<Map<String, String>> csvInputList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
         List<Map<String, Integer>> headerList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

         String fileName = "C:/test.csv";
         CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.newFormat(',').withHeader();

          try (BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
                  CSVParser dataCSVParser = new CSVParser(inputReader, format); ) {

             List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = dataCSVParser.getRecords();

             Map<String, Integer> headerMap = dataCSVParser.getHeaderMap();
              headerList.add(headerMap);
              headerList.forEach(System.out::println);

             for(CSVRecord record : csvRecords){
                 Map<String, String> inputMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                 for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> header : headerMap.entrySet()){
                     inputMap.put(header.getKey(), record.get(header.getValue()));
                 }

                 if (!inputMap.isEmpty()) {
                     csvInputList.add(inputMap);
                } 
             }

             csvInputList.forEach(System.out::println);

          } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice , really nice

Answer (score 6):

Please consider the use of [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/). This library is written according [RFC 4180 - Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). What is compatible to read such lines:

```
"aa,a","b""bb","ccc"
```

And the use is quite simple, there is just 3 classes, and a small sample according documentation:

> Parsing of a csv-string having tabs as separators, '"' as an optional
> value encapsulator, and comments starting with '#':

```
 CSVFormat format = new CSVFormat('\t', '"', '#');
 Reader in = new StringReader("a\tb\nc\td");
 String[][] records = new CSVParser(in, format).getRecords();
```

And additionally you get this parsers already available as constants:

- **DEFAULT** - Standard comma separated format as defined by RFC 4180.
- **EXCEL** - Excel file format (using a comma as the value delimiter).
- **MYSQL** - Default MySQL format used by the SELECT INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE operations.
  TDF - Tabulation delimited format.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)?

Previous question here...

[CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Looks like you can split out the header quite easily...

```
String fileName = "data.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName ));


// if the first line is the header
String[] header = reader.readNext();

// iterate over reader.readNext until it returns null
String[] line = reader.readNext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code here, being

```
while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      //reads everything in your csv
    }
```

will print all of your CSV content.

For example, the following fetches your header:

```
Reader in = ...;
 CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader("Col1", "Col2", "Col3").parse(in);
```

As suggested, life could be easier using the predefined CSVFormat from the apache commons library. Link here (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html).
Cheers.