# CSV parser using Scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n") to separate lines doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, parsing, csv

Since we know CSV files content has each line separated using `\r\n`, then we can get each line easily. Code like:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n"); 
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    scanner.next();
}
```

But how if a field of CSV file has "\r\n" inside, then this code doesn't work! Like CSV here:

```
Row1: "abc\r\nabc","abc","abc"
Row2: "efg", "efg", "efg"
Row3: "hjk", "hjk"
```

I would like using scanner to read in as:

```
"abc\r\nabc","abc","abc"
"efg", "efg", "efg"
"hjk", "hjk"
```

but if just using `\r\n`, it turns out would be：

```
“abc
abc","abc","abc"
"efg", "efg", "efg"
"hjk", "hjk"
```

What change should I do? How to modify `scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n")` to make the pattern workable?

Comment: shouldn't the delimiter be "," instead ?

Comment: I would like using scanner to separate lines, first I used bufferedreader, but it would stop when met with "\n", but I just found out scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n") doesn't work as well.. since in a field of CSV may contain "\r\n" inside.

Comment: "," can also be inside a field of CSV. In my codes, I try to separate lines first, read each line of CSV in, then in each line of fields, separate them using other pattern.

Comment: if \r\n is in between the quotation marks then it's not csv file.

Comment: i was wrong https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: @gigadot, really? so you mean a line like ("abc\r\nabc","abc","abc") can not be made as a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend you research existing CSV parsing libraries. I imagine they will do a very good job coping with *anything* that exists between your field delimeters (`""`), including the same character(s) that terminate your lines. See related question: [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java).

Failing that, I would attempt to implement the solutions presented in this SO question: [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes).

Comment: "," can also be inside a field of CSV. In my codes, I try to separate lines first, read each line of CSV in, then in each line of fields, separate them using other pattern, I have found a very useful pattern for this, but now my problem is I can't separate lines successfully.. maybe my way is too far stupid.. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @PengzhiZhou I would *strongly* recommend you seek a CSV library. Don't re-invent the wheel on this one! People have already battled these issues and have succeeded. See also the new link in my answer.

Comment: thanks for your kindly suggest, actually that is a work test, I don't think they would like to see me using other CSV library.

Comment: @PengzhiZhou Then see the other link I added to my edited answer.

Comment: I have read that post already,  that is the pattern I used to separate fields of each line, but the problem is I need to read a line of string in first, then I can apply that pattern to separate by ",". I have a csv file, I need to separate by lines first, I just have no clue how to do it. If I directly using that pattern of that post to separate an entire file, i will have no way to restore that file again using those data.

Answer (score 1):

It's always tempting to roll your own solution, but it's issues like embedded newlines that make it far easier to use a CSV library.

[Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) caters for embedded newlines (it's [compliant with RFC4180](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/csv_specification.html) - the MIME type definition of CSV), as well as embedded quotes and delimiters (all configurable). As well as being able to read into a List, Map or POJO, you can define [processors](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html) to convert or validate your data, and you'll get a lot more information when something goes wrong (the line number, row number, column number, etc).

We (the Super CSV team) have just released a [new version](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html), which brings many improvements and bug fixes as well as a [powerful new extension](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_dozer.html) that maps between CSV files and POJOs using Dozer.

It's available for [download](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/downloading.html) on SourceForge or Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the delimiter:

```
 "\"\r\n\""
```

which should work provided each line begins and ends with a **"**. Although it would still be broken if one of your strings contained *just* a newline.

Comment: this delimiter cannot find any match, only would get entire file in one string. Seems in each line break \r\n, I don't think they would be surround by "". I also have tested it in my code, sorry it doesn't work