# Accessing data in CSV file using java without sql

Tags: java, sql, csv

How can I access data in a CSV file, like I want data from from a certain cell and store it in a variable, but without using SQL. Any references would be also great to read about it

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Comment: I'm confused: Why do you think you need a SQL engine to access a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CsvFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.out.println("\n**** readLineByLineExample ****");
            String csvFilename = "C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/temp/20130128.csv";
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
            String[] col = null;
            while ((col = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                System.out.println(col[0] + " # " + col[1]);
                //System.out.println(col[0]);
            }
            csvReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

you can attach the jar from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/milyn/opencsv/1.6/opencsv-1.6.jar)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the CSV file, run it through a CSV parser, and use the API on the parser to extract whatever information you need.

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/