# JAVA parse a CSV file

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I just recently went through the exercise of going through various examples and tutorials dealing with parsing XML's - I have been introduced to JSoup, DOM, StAX, and maybe one other.

I now want to branch off into opening and reading a csv (comma deliminted file) and search for particular data.

A brief internet search shows similar to the XML exercise - plenty of options.

What technique do you recommend (within the JAVA world) for opening, reading, searching a csv file?

I guess I would also like to include writing a csv file also.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: [CSV API for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library which is simple and easy to use csv file parser. You can find [how to read](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) and [how to write](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#can-I-write) examples on FAQ of opencsv site.