# Need help string.split()

Tags: java, split

I have some data in a format like

```
int,int,'string',int,'string'
```

Every string is enclosed by '', my problems is that some strings contains commas, how can I make sure that string.split() doesn't split when inside '' ?

Comment: Use a parser for this.  `String.split()` is an entirely inadequate tool for such tasks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Comment: Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

Comment: StringUtils of Spring is very good for this kind of jobs.

Comment: Thanks Jayamohan, that was exactly my problem, and I got it working now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a Regular expression like `"/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g"` and use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and check if it works ? Something like this :

```
String str = "int,int,'string',int,'string','string,int'";
String[] arr = str.split("/('.*?'|[^',\\s]+)(?=\\s*,|\\s*$)/g");
for(String string:arr){
     System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the data yourself you can use a different delimiter which you use as the delimiter on splitting.

Alternatively you could use the split normally with the comma as a delimiter and then go through the array and for each string entry count the number of quotes found and recombine elements containing single quote which flow eachother in the array order.