# Create a new CSV file using Java

Tags: java, csv

I have to create a new CSV file and write data to that file. Here's my code snippet

```
String path = "D:\\cradius-data-local\\files\\webapps\\vcm";
String javaPath = path.replace("\\", "/");
String tempFolderPath = "zips"+File.separator+dto.getFileName();
File csvFile = null;
CSVWriter csvWriter = null;
csvFile = new File(javaPath+File.separator+tempFolderPath+File.separator+dto.getFileName()+".csv");
if(!csvFile.getParentFile().exists()){
    csvFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile), ',');
```

But when I'm trying to execute the above code, I'm getting the below error

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

The location where I want to create my new csv file is

```
javaPath+File.separator+tempFolderPath+File.separator+dto.getFileName()+".csv"
```

Which evaluates to

```
D:/cradius-data-local/files/webapps/vcm\ocr_zips\AMIT_COOL_123\AMIT_COOL_123.csv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create CSV file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837009/create-csv-file-using-java)

Comment: `D:/cradius-data-local/files/webapps/vcm\ocr_zips\AMIT_COOL_123\AMIT_COOL_123.csv` mixes both forward and backward slashes. You don't need to do **any** replacement. Let Java [do the work for you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)). Or, ever better, use the [`Path` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) rather than the mostly obsoltete `File` API.

Answer (score 1):

As Boris wrote in the comment, you can let Java do the work for you. Consider following snippet:

```
String path = "D:\\cradius-data-local\\files\\webapps\\vcm";
File file = Paths.get(path, "zips", dto.getFileName() + ".csv").toFile();
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:
String javaPath = path.replace("\\", "\"); // Create a new variable
instead of:
String javaPath = path.replace("\\", "/"); // Create a new variable