# Regular Expression for Comma Based Splitting Ignoring Commas inside Quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

In one of my projects I had to deal with Comma Separated files (CSV). I had to split data based on Comma `,` ignoring commas inside quotes (i.e. `""`) so I used an expression mentioned on another stack overflow question ([Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)). Everything was working fine until recently I noticed that it is not working for one specific scenario mentioned below.

I have a data string needed to split on Commas as:

```
20Y-62-27412,20Y6227412NK,BRACKET,101H,00D505060,H664374,06/25/2013,1,,
```

In my understanding based on expression

```
String[] rowData = str.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Data after splitting should return me an array of size 10 with last two indexes of array containing an empty string, Instead I am getting an array of size 8 being last two commas not treated as splitter. I have used this expression on several places in my application so I don't want to backtrack from this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)?

Comment: The problem is similar to parsing mathematical terms that include brackets. Most people will tell you that RegEx is **NOT** the way to do it. I'm not even sure that CSV is a regular language (my university days are long gone, so I'm not sure about that... XD)

Comment: I have Japanese characters in my file with very complex character schema inside which I don't think can be easily done with any parser. Also, RE is working fine splitting data accordingly leaving me this only problem i just discovered. Using parser will cost me make changes to my application on dozens of places which is not an option considering little time span.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [split(java.lang.String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) 
method

Your code would then look like:

```
String str = "20Y-62-27412,20Y6227412NK,BRACKET,101H,00D505060,H664374,06/25/2013,1,,";
String[] rowData = str.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
```

Comment: Perfect, It keeps the quotes and do it's job in C# so thank you!