# C# Get string between two characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like below:

```
{{"textA","textB","textC"}}
```

And currently, I'm using below code to split them:

```
string stringIWantToSplit = "{{\"textA\",\"textB\",\"textC\"}}";
string[] result = stringIWantToSplit.Split(',');
```

And I can get the below result:

```
{{"textA"
"textB"
"textC"}}
```

After that, I can manually trim out the '{' and '}' to get the final result, but here is the problem:

If the string is like below:

```
   `{{"textA","textB,textD","textC"}}`
```

Then the result will be different from Expected result

Expected result:

```
  "textA" 
  "textB,textD"
  "textC"
```

Actual result:

`{{"textA"
  "textB
  textD"
  "textC"}}`

How can I get the string between two double quotes?

---

Updated:

Just now when I checked the data, I found that some of them contains decimals i.e.

```
{{"textA","textB","",0,9.384,"textC"}}
```

Currently, I'm trying to use Jenish Rabadiya's approach, and the regex I'm using is

`(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

but with this regex, the numbers aren't selected, how to modify it so that the numbers / decimal can be selected?

Comment: Have you looked at using a Regex?

Comment: Looks related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342949/how-can-i-split-a-string-while-ignore-commas-in-between-quotes?rq=1

Comment: Stop rolling your own CSV Parser http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I'm not trying to parse a csv file, actually, I'm trying to parse a string in above format which is saved from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex like following.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1");
foreach (var match in regex.Matches("{{\"textA\",\"textB\",\"textC\"}}"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Here is working dotnet fiddle => [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YJ9n6E)

Comment: I'm trying to use your approach, but when I revised the data, there are some numbers, how can I change the regex so that the numbers can be selected?(Please take a look at my update)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string will always look like your examples, you can use a simple regular expression to get your strings out:

```
string s = "{{\"textA\",\"textB,textD\",\"textC\"}}";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "\\\".*?\\\""))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you,

```
List<string> specialChars = new List<string>() {",", "{{","}}" };
string stringIWantToSplit = "{{\"textA\",\"textB,textD\",\"textC\"}}";
string[] result = stringIWantToSplit.Split(new char[] {'"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(text => !specialChars.Contains(text)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this regex makes simple:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally modified the regex to this:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|(\d*\.?\d*)[^"' {},]
```

And this finally works:

Sample:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vg4jUh