# Regex divide string by commas ignoring function syntax

Tags: regex, scala

I need a regex that substitutes a string by looking at their commas.
For example the string:

```
str1 = "a,b,12,func(a,b),8,bob,func(1,2))"
```

should be transformed as following:

```
str1_transformed = "a;b;12;func(a,b);8;bob;func(1,2))"
```

I cannot substitute every "," with a ";" because it will look like:

```
str1_wrong = "a;b;12;func(a;b);8;bob;func(1;2))"
```

How can I deal with it?
I looked at the following threads without success:
[How can I Split(',') a string while ignore commas in between quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342949/how-can-i-split-a-string-while-ignore-commas-in-between-quotes)
[Regular Expression for Comma Based Splitting Ignoring Commas inside Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939307/regular-expression-for-comma-based-splitting-ignoring-commas-inside-quotes)

Comment: Which programming language are you coding it? I've guessed it is C#, if I'm wrong. please retag it.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I'm using scala, but regex should work indifferently by the program language

Comment: I agree that there should be no difference, but the actuality is that different languages and libraries implement regex differently.

Comment: You may try `,(?![^()]*\))` to select commas that are outside of brackets. See demo here https://regex101.com/r/8X8TWH/1

Comment: @revo Thanks. This work great. Now I try to understand it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that you won't have unbalanced or escaped brackets below regex works well:

```
,(?![^()]*\))
```

Breakdown:

- `,` Match a comma
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `[^()]*\)` That means, recent matched comma shouldn't follow a closing bracket without matching opening bracket
- `)` End of lookahead

C# code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@",(?![^()]*\))");
string result = regex.Replace(@"a,b,12,func(a,b),8,bob,func(1,2))", @";");
```

Comment: Is the `)` inside `[^()]` actually needed?

Comment: No it doesn't change result but makes engine to fail fast when more than one `)` character are following each other.