# Java Regex for , not followed by a space

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm trying to seperate a csv file values using a regex expression, The problem is that there are quotation marks surrounding sentences and the regex I've tried doesn't seem to do it correctly.

```
"All's Well, Ends Well 2012",Comedy
```

This is one of the strings that is contained in the CSV and I've tried separating it with quite a few different regex statements but it keeps just returning the whole string without seperating it.

Any advice or work arounds regarding the regex I can use for this ?

Comment: Probably `(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)` or better a CSV parser !

Comment: You should use a CSV parser library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex with `split()` that splits by commas only when an even number of quotes appear in the rest of the input:

```
String[] parts = line.split(",(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

See this code execute in a [live demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/RA7B73)

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly ^^ I'm using it on processing and not sure if I can include external libraries in it. so thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

The best advice is to use a CVS parser, eg http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/, regex is not the best choice for parsing CSV

Comment: Unless you are good at regex :)