# Java: String.Split stops recording after a number input

Tags: java

Background: I'm trying to read from a csv file that I made with excel.

An example line of something I'm trying to read would be

```
Text,435,435,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

My code is

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Items.csv"));
    br.readLine();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // use comma as separator
        String[] stats = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        for(int i =0; i<stats.length; i++){
            System.out.print(i + ",");
            System.out.print(stats[i] + "," + \n);
        }
```

This gives an output of my String[]. However this gives an output of

```
0,Text,1,435,2,435,3,,4,,5,,6,,7,,8,,9,,10,,11,,12,,13,,14,,15,20,
```

An input of

```
Text,435,435,,,,,,,,,,1800,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Gives:

```
0,Amplifying Tome,1,435,2,435,3,,4,,5,,6,,7,,8,,9,,10,,11,1800,
```

Why is my array stopping at the first number it finds?

Comment: Are you sure you want split, and not something like [openCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java) or [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)?

Comment: Is every number separated by just one `,`?

Comment: What output do you want? Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

According to [String.split(String) javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29%20String.split%28%29%20javadoc) "trailing empty strings are not included in the resulting array".

If you know how many columns there are exactly, you can use the String.split(String, int) method, with a positive number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `,`s separating the numbers, you need to set the delimiter to one or more. Try :

```
String[] stats = line.split("[,]+"); <-- signifies one or more comma
```

Without using the `+`, what's happening is it is reading a single `,` as a delimiter, then the next `,` will be added to the array as String, then the next `,` is a delimiter, next `,` a String, next `,` a delimiter, next `,` a String and so on.