# How to read array representation from property file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, property-files

I would like to read a property file which has array format.

I have this property file:

```
students.student[0] = ABC
students.student[0].marks[0] = 10
students.student[0].marks[1] = 20
students.student[0].marks[2] = 30
students.student[0].marks[3] = 40
students.student[0].marks[4] = 50
students.student[0].marks[5] = 60
students.student[0].marks[6] = 70

students.student[1] = XYZ
students.student[1].marks[0] = 10
students.student[1].marks[1] = 20
students.student[1].marks[2] = 30
students.student[1].marks[3] = 40
students.student[1].marks[4] = 50
students.student[1].marks[5] = 60
students.student[1].marks[6] = 70
```

I am trying to read this property file as follow:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("students")
@PropertySource("classpath:student.properties")
public class StudentProperties{
   List<Student> students = new ArryaList<Student>();
   public static class Student
   {
      String name;
      List<Marks> marks = new ArrayList<Marks>;
      public static class Marks
      {
         int marks;
          //getters and setters
      }     
      //getters and setters
   }
   //getters and setters
 }
```

But It is not setting values. 
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping POJO is not in correct format, In `Student` class Just have `List<Integer>`

```
@ConfigurationProperties("students")
@PropertySource("classpath:student.properties")
public class StudentProperties{
List<Student> student = new ArryaList<Student>();
   public static class Student
      {
         String name;
         List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //getters and setters
     }
     //getters and setters
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While possible in some form ( [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value) ), this would be considered an abuse of the application.properties file which is meant to be used for configuration and not as a data store.

I would recommend you save your data in a [CSV](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001356.htm) file, and parse them using one of the many suited libraries, ex - [How to easily process CSV file to List<MyClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485041/how-to-easily-process-csv-file-to-listmyclass)