# JAVA - How to add content of CSV specific column to List<String>?

Tags: java, list, csv, parsing, arraylist

This is my CSV, first line is header, Akt (pan), Mc1-1 and etc. is content. 
I need to create a function that extracts content of SearchTerm column and adds it to a `List<String>`.

I tried it with this piece of code but my next processing requires to have `List<String>` and not `List<String[]>`. Is there a way to do that or is there any way i can take parsed `List<String[]>` and make it into `List<String>` only containing all the search terms?

[image: My CSV]

```
public List<String> listAllSearchTerms() throws FileNotFoundException {
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.selectIndexes(0);
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("D:\\Projects\\cstocs-test-dev-bitbucket\\cstocs-test-core\\src\\main\\resources\\data\\searchterm.csv"));
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    allRows.remove(0);
    for (String[] strings : allRows) {
        returnList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: Please write what is the problem with the mentioned sample of code? It seems that the sample already does what you want to do.

Comment: Probably create a bean class for the `SearchTerms` and follow this question will get the clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485041/how-to-easily-process-csv-file-to-listmyclass

Answer (score 1):

If you know which column SearchTerm is you can replace the for loop with

```
for (String[] strings : allRows) {
     returnList.add(strings[0]); //Assumes it's the first column
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> is there any way i can take parsed List and make it into
>   List only containing all the search terms?

```
    String[] strArr1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] strArr2 = {"d", "e", "f"};

    List<String[]> stringArrList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringArrList.add(strArr1);
    stringArrList.add(strArr2);

    List<String> collect = stringArrList.stream()
            .map(arr -> arr[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(collect);
```

output:

```
[a, d]
```

Comment: I think just the first column "SearchTerm" was intended. Then instead of `flatMap` there should be `.map(arr -> arr[0])`. Though a Stream solution is perfect.