# What's the most efficient way to write this method?

Tags: java, performance

The method returns an "Ingredient" object that is constructed from a given line in a recipe txt file. Note: an `InvalidIngredientException` is like an `Ingredient` version of an `InputMismatchException`. This isn't thrown by any of the lines in the given recipe file.

```
public static Ingredient parseString(String line)
        throws InvalidIngredientException {        
    double quantity = 1;
    String measurement = "";
    String[] parts = line.split(";");
    if (parts.length == 1) {
        throw new InvalidIngredientException(EXP_MSG);
    }
    if (!parts[0].trim().isEmpty()
            && !(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]) == 1)) {
        quantity = Double.parseDouble(parts[0].trim());
    }
    if (!parts[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
        measurement = parts[1].trim();
    } 
    return new Ingredient(quantity, measurement, parts[2].trim());
}
```

A recipe file looks like this:

```
Cranberry Oatmeal Chews
8; tablespoon; butter
2; tablespoon; oil
1; cup; light brown sugar
1; ; zest of one orange
6; tablespoon; sour cream
2; teaspoon; vanilla
1.5; cup; flour
.5; teaspoon; baking soda
1; teaspoon; cinammon
.5; teaspoon; salt
2; cup; oats
1.5; cup; dried cranberries
.5; cup; walnuts
```

The method works, but I feel like it could use less code.

Comment: Does "efficient" mean "performant" or "fewer lines of code"? It's not clear to me which you're asking for.

Comment: @DM I meant fewer lines of code, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Put all the code on the same line.

Comment: Remove the `!(Double.parseDouble(parts[0]) == 1)` condition. Your performing an expensive operation, in order to save exactly the same operation in one case. So you save nothing but perform the operation twice when the condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called "bind CSV row to an object". There are quite a few good libraries for parsing CSV, most mature ones offering the binding functionality as well. Also there are annotation-based code generation enabled frameworks like Lombok or Jackson which make Java one step closer to convenient languages like Scala, by saving you from writing very verbose getters/setters by hand (with a minor complication to the build process, maybe).

And once you use correct search term you will find a plenty of examples. One doing just what I described above is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485041/how-to-easily-process-csv-file-to-listmyclass), below is a version adjusted to your naming. It is using Jackson.

Object definition with Jackson [annotations](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html):

```java
@JsonPropertyOrder({"quantity", "measure", "ingredient"})
public class Ingredient {
    public double quantity;
    public String measure;
    public int ingredient;
}
```

Invocation code with the Jackson [CsvMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvMapper.html):

```
List<Ingredient> result = new CsvMapper()
    .readerWithTypedSchemaFor(Ingredient.class)
    .readValues(csvFile)
    .readAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Java, so there might be minor errors in this code. Feel free to edit if you see one.

Coming from a C# perspective, I'd make the following changes:

1. Move the `.trim()` calls to one place. Here I do that just after splitting the input lines into `parts` by creating a `Stream` using [`of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) then calling [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) (assuming Java 8 or newer).
2. Remove the lines instantiating default values for `quantity` and `measurement`. Because we don't have to trim, we can use the ternary operator to declare and instantiate the variables on the same line.
3. Don't check if `parts[1]` is empty. Since `""` is the fallback value, it doesn't matter if `parts[1]` is also `""`. This also means you don't need the intermediate `measurement` variable.

```java
public static Ingredient parseString(String line)
        throws InvalidIngredientException {        
    String[] parts = Stream.of(line.split(";")).map(p => p.trim()).toArray();
    if (parts.length == 1) {
        throw new InvalidIngredientException(EXP_MSG);
    }
    double quantity = parts[0].isEmpty() ? 1 : Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);    
    return new Ingredient(quantity, parts[1], parts[2]);
}
```

---

You also have the potential to throw errors other than `InvalidIngredientException` if `parts.length == 0` or if `parts[0]` cannot be parsed to a `Double`. I'm not sure how strict you're supposed to be when declaring which exceptions your method can throw, but here's a version that should catch any exceptions and only return the `InvalidIngredientException` you declared.

```java
public static Ingredient parseString(String line)
        throws InvalidIngredientException {     
    try { 
        String[] parts = Stream.of(line.split(";")).map(p => p.trim()).toArray();
        double quantity = parts[0].isEmpty() ? 1 : Double.parseDouble(parts[0]); 
        return new Ingredient(quantity, parts[1], parts[2]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InvalidIngredientException(EXP_MSG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few little things that you can do to make your code look better and a increase the performance a bit also.

1. Change the regex when splitting the line to "\s;\s". This way you avoid the trim() calls multiple times
2. Use `else if...else` syntax. This will make your code not only a bit shorter but also easier to read.