# JavaCSV not reading any rows

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to parse CSV file using JavaCSV:

```
CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("test.csv", ';', Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String[] strArr = reader.getHeaders();
```

`test.csv` is valid csv file with `';'` as delimiter (file exported from Excel).
I converted file to UTF-8 encoding using Notepad++.
After this `strArr` is empty.

Beginning of `test.csv' file:

```
nr inwentarza;temat;projektant;rytownik;wydawca;sygnatury;datowanie;miejce wydania;opis;inskrypcje;wymiary;bibliografia;Seria;uwagi;kategoria;Teka;Column1;Column3;Column4;Column5;Column6;Column7;Column8;Column9;Column10;Column11;Column12;Column13;Column14;Column15;Column16;Column17;Column18;Column19;Column20;Column21;Column22;Column23;Column24;Column25;Column26;Column27;Column28;Column29;Column30;Column31;Column32;Column33;Column34;Column35;Column36;Column37;Column38;Column39;Column40;Column41;Column42;Column43;Column44;Column45;Column46;Column47;Column48;Column49;Column50;Column51;Column52;Column53;Column54;Column55;Column56;Column57;Column58;Column59;Column60;Column61;Column62;Column63;Column64;Column65;Column66;Column67;Column68;Column69;Column70;Column71;Column72;Column73;Column74;Column75;Column76;Column77;Column78;Column79;Column80;Column81;Column82;Column83;Column84;Column85;Column86;Column87;Column88;Column89;Column90;Column91;Column92;Column93;Column94;Column95;Column96;Column97;Column98;Column99;Column100;Column101;Column102;Column103;Column104;Column105;Column106;Column107;Column108;Column109;Column110;Column111;Column112;Column113;Column114;Column115;Column116;Column117;Column118;Column119;Column120;Column121;Column122;Column123;Column124;Column125;Column126;Column127;Column128;Column129;Column130;Column131;Column132;Column133;Column134;Column135;Column136;Column137;Column138;Column139;Column140;Column141;Column142;Column143;Column144;Column145;Column146;Column147;Column148;Column149;Column150;Column151;Column152;Column153;Column154;Column155;Column156;Column157;Column158;Column159;Column160;Column161;Column162;Column163;Column164;Column165;Column166;Column167;Column168;Column169;Column170;Column171;Column172;Column173;Column174;Column175;Column176;Column177;Column178;Column179;Column180;Column181;Column182;Column183;Column184;Column185;Column186;Column187;Column188;Column189;Column190;Column191;Column192;Column193;Column194;Column195;Column196;Column197;Column198;Column199;Column200;Column201;Column202;Column203;Column204;Column205;Column206;Column207;Column208;Column209;Column210;Column211;Column212;Column213;Column214;Column215;Column216;Column217;Column218;Column219;Column220;Column221;Column222;Column223;Column224;Column225;Column226;Column227;Column228;Column229;Column230;Column231;Column232;Column233;Column234;Column235;Column236;Column237;Column238;Column239;Column240;Column241
9455;Wzrok;Maerten de Vos;Adriaen Collaert;Eduwart van Hoeswinckel ;brak;;;;;;;Zmysły;;alegoria świecka;153;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
9456;Słuch;Maerten de Vos;Adriaen Collaert;Eduwart van Hoeswinckel ;brak;;;;;;;Zmysły;napis PONĘTOWSKIEGO Auditus;alegoria świecka;153;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Try providing the full path to the file.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to read the rows and/or what error you are getting.

Comment: Maybe this could help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php) (if you're using this library), you have to call `readHeaders` before `getHeaders`.

```
CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("test.csv", ';', Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
reader.readHeaders();
String[] strArr = reader.getHeaders();
```