# Splitting CSV files but ignoring commas inside quotations

Tags: java, csv

Here's a sample of my csv file

```
5,DENTISTRY,MAJOR,null,TRUE
6,DERMATOLOGY,MAJOR,null,TRUE
7,"EYE, EAR, NOSE, THROAT",MAJOR,null,TRUE
8,EMERGENCY MEDICINE,MAJOR,null,TRUE
```

How do I split this csv file while ignoring the comma inside double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a proper CSV parsing library, rather than trying to simply split the lines.

Parsing CSV well is harder than it initially seems, and you're much better off using a high quality, working library.

You can find recommendations about CSV libraries here:
[CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)