# Splitting a csv file which is having comma snd special characters in its data in Java

Tags: java, csv

I want to split a **CSV file** which is having comma and other special characters in its data using java. I tried regex way of splitting like `line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);` and more similar kind of things. But splitting is wrong in some rows.

CSV is having around 3000 rows. Some of them are not properly getting split.
Please suggest a standard way to split the data in csv file.

Comment: There are already a large number of CSV parsing libraries out there, any one of which you can use.

Comment: how should your regular expression know if the comma is a separator or not?

Comment: I've had success with Commons CSV. User guide here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you have standard desktop or web application [Apache-CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)might help you. If you are dealing with some kind of "Big Data" technologies have a look at [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

Comment: 3000 rows != bigData

Comment: @thomas Agree. But nobody tells you if this is one of a million csv files or if a line contains 100MB of data. According to the question this sounds unlikely but I wanted to point out that the pure amount of rows doesn't tell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separating values using a comma, you can use tab(\t).
File can be saved with .csv extension. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all special character to `+` and then split

```
String result = str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
```