# Regex to split CSV string containing quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have a CSV string that looks something like this:

```
"DOE, JOHN W", "35", "$12,945", "M"
```

I'm working with Java, so normally I would just split a csv with a comma as the delimiter; however, since some of the values have commas in them, I need a different way to split the string; I don't have much experience with regex at all so was wondering if anybody had any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: consider using a csv parser instead of Regex

Comment: When parsing (or generating) CSV data, use a CSV library. Regex is not an adequate tool for parsing CSV.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the other comments, your best bet is to use a CSV library, there are scenarios where you may still need to parse a comma separated string with regex. For this scenario, the below regex should work.

```
"([^"]+)"
```

This regex will match any character that is not a quotation mark within quotes.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l8jGIj/2)

Comment: And now we wait until OP say that quotes can have escaped inner quotes. Lets simply use CSV parser which handles all kinds of traps like this one.

Comment: Again, I don't disagree - but I have certainly ran into scenarios where a CSV parser is not an option, primarily when scripting other platforms. In those cases, a quick regex tailored to your specific scenario can suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex (maybe)

```
([^\",\s][^\"]*)
```

Comment: first character can not be double quote or comma or space but from the second character can not be double quote only

Comment: OK, but do we really need `{1}` here? Why? `[..]` character class can match only *one* character from specified set, so `{1}` seems redundant and only provides unnecessary confusion.