# How to find the values of an elements from API response (export to csv)

Tags: java, csv

I have API response like below

```
"Name","Product ID","Product Description","Location", "Product Family","Product Type","Serial Number"
"W2DY-BL3I-AR7Z","ABC67-HW","Security Appliance","USA", "Cloud Managed Security Appliances","Security","Q2AY-YX3W-VRXZ"
```

First line is CSV headers & second line is values.

I want to get values of Product ID, Location & Serial Number like below:

```
ABC67-HW
USA
Q2AY-YX3W-VRXZ
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take both the first line and second line into ArrayList.

let's say headers ArrayList

let's say values ArrayList

```
int index = headers.get("Product ID");
if (index >= 0){
    String productId = values.get(index);
}
```

and keep reading the other headers also exactly the same way and keep obtaing their respcting values.

Comment: how to take lines into arraylist? any suggestions? i got both  lines in 1 single variable. like:

String exportDataReceived = somefunction(apiURL);

exportDataReceived  contains both lines.

Comment: Split the exportDataReceived by "\n" a new line separator. Now you would have two strings in an array, the first one is CSV headers, and the second one being their corresponding vlaues. You can keep on tokenizing from there on. Many thanks!

Comment: eg: 
String headers = exportDataReceived.split("\n")[0];
String values    = exportDataReceived.split("\n")[1]