# Can you recommend a Java library for reading (and possibly writing) CSV files?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

Can you recommend a Java library for reading, parsing, validating and mapping rows in a comma separated value (CSV) file to Java value objects (JavaBeans)?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Comment: [Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) has just been released. It includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections)

Comment: I've just added a detailed example below!

Comment: [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is another option. Reads and writes files in variations of the Comma Separated Value (CSV) format, and Tab-Delimited too.

Comment: [uniVocity](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) is the fastest in my experience. It is also very customizable.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

We have used
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
with good success

I also came across another question with good links:
[Java lib or app to convert CSV to XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123/csv-file-to-xml)

Comment: I used opencsv but it failed when parsing some escape characters in my dataset. I recommend Super CSV. It is way more robust.

Answer (score 26):

[Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net) is a great choice for reading/parsing, validating and mapping CSV files to POJOs!

We (the Super CSV team) have just released a new version (you can [download](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/downloading.html) it from SourceForge or Maven).

## Reading a CSV file

The following example uses `CsvDozerBeanReader` (a new reader we've just released that uses [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) for bean mapping with deep mapping and index-based mapping support) - it's based on the example from our [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_dozer.html). If you don't need the Dozer functionality (or you just want a simple standalone dependency), then you can use `CsvBeanReader` instead (see this [code example](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html)).

### Example CSV file

Here is an example CSV file that represents responses to a survey. It has a header and 3 rows of data, all with 8 columns.

```
age,consentGiven,questionNo1,answer1,questionNo2,answer2,questionNo3,answer3
18,Y,1,Twelve,2,Albert Einstein,3,Big Bang Theory
,Y,1,Thirteen,2,Nikola Tesla,3,Stargate
42,N,1,,2,Carl Sagan,3,Star Wars
```

### Defining the mapping from CSV to POJO

Each row of CSV will be read into a [SurveyResponse](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/org/supercsv/mock/dozer/SurveyResponse.html) class, each of which has a List of [Answer](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref-test/org/supercsv/mock/dozer/Answer.html)s. In order for the mapping to work, your classes should be valid Javabeans (i.e have a default no-arg constructor and have getters/setters defined for each field).

In Super CSV you define the mapping with a simple String array - each element of the array corresponds to a column in the CSV file.

With `CsvDozerBeanMapper` you can use:

- simple field mappings (e.g. `firstName`)
- deep mappings (e.g. `address.country.code`)
- indexed mapping (e.g. `middleNames[1]` - zero-based index for arrays or Collections)
- deep + indexed mapping (e.g. `person.middleNames[1]`)

The following is the field mapping for this example - it uses a combination of these:

```
private static final String[] FIELD_MAPPING = new String[] { 
        "age",                   // simple field mapping (like for CsvBeanReader)
        "consentGiven",          // as above
        "answers[0].questionNo", // indexed (first element) + deep mapping
        "answers[0].answer", 
        "answers[1].questionNo", // indexed (second element) + deep mapping
        "answers[1].answer", 
        "answers[2].questionNo", 
        "answers[2].answer" };
```

### Conversion and Validation

Super CSV has a useful library of [cell processors](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/cell_processors.html), which can be used to convert the Strings from the CSV file to other data types (e.g. Date, Integer), or to do constraint validation (e.g. mandatory/optional, regex matching, range checking).

Using cell processors is *entirely optional* - without them each column of CSV will be a String, so each field must be a String also.

The following is the cell processor configuration for the example. As with the field mapping, each element in the array represents a CSV column. It demonstrates how cell processors can transform the CSV data to the data type of your field, and how they can be chained together.

```
final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { 
    new Optional(new ParseInt()), // age
    new ParseBool(),              // consent
    new ParseInt(),               // questionNo 1
    new Optional(),               // answer 1
    new ParseInt(),               // questionNo 2
    new Optional(),               // answer 2
    new ParseInt(),               // questionNo 3
    new Optional()                // answer 3
};
```

### Reading

Reading with Super CSV is very flexible: you supply your own `Reader` (so you can read from a file, the classpath, a zip file, etc), and the delimiter and quote character are configurable via [preferences](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html) (of which there are a number of pre-defined configurations that cater for most usages).

The code below is pretty self-explanatory.

1. Create the reader (with your `Reader` and preferences)
2. (Optionally) read the header
3. Configure the bean mapping
4. Keep calling `read()` until you get a `null` (end of file)
5. Close the reader

**Code:**

```
ICsvDozerBeanReader beanReader = null;
try {
    beanReader = new CsvDozerBeanReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME),
        CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

    beanReader.getHeader(true); // ignore the header
    beanReader.configureBeanMapping(SurveyResponse.class, FIELD_MAPPING);

    SurveyResponse surveyResponse;
    while( (surveyResponse = 
        beanReader.read(SurveyResponse.class, processors)) != null ) {
        System.out.println(
            String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, surveyResponse=%s",
                beanReader.getLineNumber(), beanReader.getRowNumber(), 
                surveyResponse));
    }

} finally {
    if( beanReader != null ) {
        beanReader.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
lineNo=2, rowNo=2, surveyResponse=SurveyResponse [age=18, consentGiven=true, answers=[Answer [questionNo=1, answer=Twelve], Answer [questionNo=2, answer=Albert Einstein], Answer [questionNo=3, answer=Big Bang Theory]]]
lineNo=3, rowNo=3, surveyResponse=SurveyResponse [age=null, consentGiven=true, answers=[Answer [questionNo=1, answer=Thirteen], Answer [questionNo=2, answer=Nikola Tesla], Answer [questionNo=3, answer=Stargate]]]
lineNo=4, rowNo=4, surveyResponse=SurveyResponse [age=42, consentGiven=false, answers=[Answer [questionNo=1, answer=null], Answer [questionNo=2, answer=Carl Sagan], Answer [questionNo=3, answer=Star Wars]]]
```

### More Information

You can find a lot more information on the [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net)!

Comment: You should probably add a disclaimer

Comment: Hi @GilbertS that's literally the 2nd sentence, but I also haven't worked on that project for years now....so <shrugs>. Unless you mean a disclaimer about never using CSV (which I could totally get behind haha).

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/). Simple to use, and did everything I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Hey, I have an open-source project for that: [JFileHelpers](http://jfilehelpers.com). I think the main advantage is that it uses Java Annotations, take a look:

If you have this bean:

```
@FixedLengthRecord()
public class Customer {
    @FieldFixedLength(4)
    public Integer custId;

    @FieldAlign(alignMode=AlignMode.Right)
    @FieldFixedLength(20)
    public String name;

    @FieldFixedLength(3)
    public Integer rating;

    @FieldTrim(trimMode=TrimMode.Right)
    @FieldFixedLength(10)
    @FieldConverter(converter = ConverterKind.Date, 
    format = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    public Date addedDate;

    @FieldFixedLength(3)
    @FieldOptional
    public String stockSimbol;    
}
```

And wants to parse this file:

```
....|....1....|....2....|....3....|....4                
1   Antonio Pereira     10012-12-1978ABC
2   Felipe Coury          201-01-2007
3   Anderson Polga       4212-11-2007DEF
```

All you have to do is this:

```
FileHelperEngine<Customer> engine = 
    new FileHelperEngine<Customer>(Customer.class); 
List<Customer> customers = 
    new ArrayList<Customer>();

customers = engine.readResource(
    "/samples/customers-fixed.txt");
```

Also, it supports master-detail, date and format conversion, and a lot more. Let me know what you think!

Best regards!

Comment: are you the developer ? the project seems dead. Most attractive approach from the given code sample.

Comment: Yes, I am the developer and the project is very stale indeed. I have been searching a new maintainer for a long time :)

Comment: I would do some bug fixing if you hadn't put GPL on it, but something more commercially friendly.

Comment: @koma this code is meant to be MIT licensed. If I gix this, would you like to work on it? I can't continue maintaining it.

Comment: please, publish it on maven central

Answer (score 3):

I find [Flatpack](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/) to be really good with handling quirky CSV files (escapes, quotes, bad records, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The CSV File to XML question asked previously seems to answer all my questions.

OpenCSV (http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) also does binding to JavaBeans using a Column Position Mapping Strategy

```
  ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
  strat.setType(YourOrderBean.class);
  String[] columns = new String[] {"name", "orderNumber", "id"}; // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
  strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

  CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
  List list = csv.parse(strat, yourReader);
```

JSEFA (http://jsefa.sourceforge.net) also seems to do everything I need - particularly binding to Java objects - in addition to supporting FLR and XML

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success both parsing and writing CSV files from Java with [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).  If you want to read or write Excel compatible spreadsheet with Java, the [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library from Apache is the way to go.

Comment: CVS is another thing, but at least the link is correct... :-P
I see the common typo often in our own code, and it is a pain to correct (when used in several places)! :-(

Answer (score 0):

See [CVSBeans](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvbeans/)