# Java - Storing Information

Tags: java, storage

I need to create a program that can store the names of 5 people and a status message for each. It must be able to display the names and statuses. I also want to be able to change the statuses of any person.

Here on Stack Overflow, the most relevant example to my question is this one. [storing names and other information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415008/storing-names-and-other-information)

However, not specific enough as I am a beginner. Any suggestions on good tutorials for such assignment?

I am using Eclipse

Comment: Learn to use Database or file handling

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you're a beginner, you are likely following a book, tutorial or course. Either look ahead to the topics Nabin mentions, or ask your teacher.

Comment: You could lay out a fixed width binary file. Assuming you can define a maximum width for `name` and `status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend using a Hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and using put to assign name to the key set and a message to the value set.

```
myMap.put("john","This person is never in"); etc
Set set = myMap.entrySet();

// check set values
System.out.println("Set values: " + set);
```

to print out name and status

Comment: Thank you - I will work with this