# Read and then Update a field in CSV using Java

Tags: java, csv, sql-update

I want to read CSV file and if decrement a field in the same CSV file. How can i do this in Java?

Comment: what do you mean by "if decrement a field in the same CSV file"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons has a CSV parser https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: I got how to read using common-csv jar but not how to update a specific field. 
Can you please give an example ?

Comment: You are not going to be able to update in place (files are stored linearly on disk).  But you can read from a file replace the lines or fields you want to change and then write out the new CSV.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397907/updating-specific-cell-csv-file-using-java