# How to read and write same excel sheet in Jmeter?

Tags: excel, jmeter, read-write, dynamic-values

I have csv as follows:
url, Expected Reponse, Actual Response, Status

I found various sites explaining how to write to Excel file but can find solution for writing Actual Response to the same file, from where i read.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: You want to update existing csv file or create file?

Comment: Existing csv file

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: add more details on your test plan

Answer (score 0):

To update existing file you must write a new file with context.delete old file and rename new file to old file.

In jmeter you can execute java  using JSR223 Sampler with language Java.

See [java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397907/updating-specific-cell-csv-file-using-java).