# Create a CSV file

Tags: csv, jython

I have a log file with data inside.

I would like to convert this file into a CSV (Excel) file.

I use Eclipse and write in Jython (all latest versions) but when I try to import CSV files I always get this error:

> ImportError: no module named csv.

Do you know why?

This is my program:

```
import csv
r = open('file.log') 
w = open('newfile.csv','w') 
writer = csv.writer(w)
for row in r.readlines():
    writer.writerow(row.split())
r.close() 
w.close()
```

---

Now I tried openCSV. The CSV file is created, but it is empty.

In fact, the problem comse from the `writeAll`.

If I put `writeNext`, only one line appears in the CSV file (that's normal), but with `writeAll`, the file is empty.

Do you know how I can resolve my problems?

This is my program:

```
from au.com.bytecode.opencsv import *
from java.io import *
for line in open("out.log"):
    try :   
        en = line.split(" ")
        writer = CSVWriter(FileWriter("out.csv"))
        writer.writeAll(en)
    except : IOException
```

Answer (score 2):

Jython doesn't seem to have a `csv` module (it's odd, though, it's documented in some places). Instead, you should use a Java library to accomplish the same. It seems that people like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), but you can decide for yourself ([there's a question about good Java CSV libraries on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files)).

I can't weigh in with certainty as to whether or not this elusive CSV module actually exists. However, you can always use an existing Java library.

Comment: Why is `csv` listed in the [Jython library documentation](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/csv.html)? That's quite confusing!

Comment: @mgiuca that's odd, because it seems like it's documented in one place and not the other. I couldn't find anything like it in the Jython source, so I think it's safe to assume that it either doesn't exist or isn't in perfect working order. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks I'll go to the see the OpenCSV.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like csv is implemented in Jython 2.5.3. I tried the examples from [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/csv/) and they work.

Comment: also works in 2.5.2 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone/2.5.2