# ignoring commas when reading from csv files in java

Tags: java

How do I store a string containing quotes or commas in to a csv file and retrieve it later without having my output split up?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java

Answer (score 3):

Best thing is to use api's meant for reading/writing csv's like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

[Can you recommend a Java library for reading (and possibly writing) CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse it yourself, use a library like this to do so: http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html

This way, you don't need to worry about double quotes or commas in the string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Values are quoted, so any comma inside a pair of quotes is ignored.

Quotes are escaped by doubling. So any sequence of two quotes inside a value is replaced by a single quote.

You can read the details in [RFC 4180.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)