# Is there any way to import a .txt file in Excel using java?

Tags: java, excel

i want to know if it's possible to import a text file in excel through java code.
I know that we can use directly Excel and open a text file.
But for me i want to do it with java because i have a java program that create a text file everyday and after i want to open it with excel automatically.

I don't want to loose my time to open Excel, then click import , then choose file, then...
is it possible to do fastly with java?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution here would be to have your Java code create a [Comma Seperated Value (CSV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. They are easy to create and easy for Excel to open (no extra clicks required).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;

class ExcelStarter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start excel.exe _pathtoexcelfile_");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to open an excel file but import a text file with excel using java

Comment: Replace with _pathtoexcelfile_ with your text file location. As long as its a type supported by excel (text, csv, etc..) then you can open it. There's no difference. Try this. It works.

Comment: It's simple with Ritch Melton tips Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can parse your text file and put the data in a worksheet using the [Apache XSSF library for xlsx](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). And then save it. 10 minutes of research should be sufficient to find what you need.

Comment: i'm beginner i really don't know what and how to do with Apaxhe XSSF library for xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I have used Apache POI and their [HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). It has a Java API with which to read Excel files.

If it is a CSV (Comma Separate Value) file, you may also want to see this question [Can you recommend a java library for reading and possibly writing csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files)

Comment: I have corrected the second link. The first link, HSSF, might be a good place to start.