# Java: reading from txt file with quotation marks 

Tags: java

I tried to search through the web, but not get the answer for my problem. I have a csv file with a line: `"Good morning" he said`. My program just reads the text from file and print out:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("XXXX/myfile.csv"));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

However, the output has more quotation marks than the original:

```
"""Good morning"" he said."
```

Can you tell me how to escape those quotation marks so that it prints out as in the file?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738569/splitting-java-string-with-quotation-marks

Comment: The output seems to be `He said, "Good morning" he said` if we replace `line0` with `line`.

Comment: @Adel: I know that post, I just want to print out as original

Comment: Your input is not a CSV file and your code has nothing to do with the output you present. Please explain what you are trying to do and what code you actually have.

Comment: Can we have all the code btw?

Comment: What, please do not downvote, I am new to java. What I want is just one quotation mark like in the file

Comment: There's no way that code produces the output you claim, besides that it's not even the same string. How are you viewing the output? How are you running the code? What information are you omitting from your question?

Comment: Funny, someone keeps voting down. Please answer it professionally

Comment: It's impossible to answer as it stands, because if the file contains what you claim it does, and the code is as you claim it is, the string will be printed precisely as it exists in the file.

Comment: Hi Dave, why did you modify to this: He said, "Good morning" he said?

Comment: @DavidNg Hi David, please re-read the edit history, and ask the right person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a CSV file, I doubt your field delimeter for that CSV file is `"`. This extra quotes will be saved in the CSV file, but wont show up when you open it using Excel or other spreadsheet type program. Check it by opening in a text editor like notepad and see.

Comment: You are correct, I copied the CSV file from Windows machine, and then edit in Mac so the delimiters changes somehow, some even are hidden. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

```
str.replaceAll("\\\"{2}", "\"");
```

Comment: @DaveNewton - OP has listed "regex" as tag in his original post