# Looking for a java CSV library that allows reading columns by name

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

Also, allows handling of long rows in a readable/easy manner, in writing them as well as in reading them.

I've looked into `opencsv` but it does not refer to elements in row in any sequential fashion, and `supercsv` does not allow looking into column by name but number only.

Another caveat - for which I need to be able to address columns by name - is that the number of columns is not constant, and only part of the column headers are constant, something like:

```
Name|Number|Color1|Color2......|Color67|
```

where not all colors between 1 and 67 are present in any given CSV file.

Comment: Does this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files help?

Comment: not exactly, as I've already found it and read the answers, but trying again now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't really speak to opencsv, but if you have a fixed number of fields [you might be able to use the JavaBean binding to do something like this](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration).

[Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net) however, definitely supports reading and writing CSV rows by name using CsvBeanReader, CsvDozerBeanReader or CsvMapReader (and their writing equivalents).

If you prefer to keep things simple and use a map (with the column name as key, and the column value as the value) then you could use [CsvMapReader](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvMapReader.html). There are examples on [reading](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html#Reading_with_CsvMapReader) and [writing](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_writing.html#Writing_with_CsvMapWriter) with CsvMapReader on the Super CSV website.

A reading example:

```
 ICsvMapReader mapReader = new CsvMapReader(
      new FileReader("foo.csv"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);
 try {
  final String[] headers = mapReader.getHeader(true);
  Map<String, String> row;
  while( (row = mapReader.read(headers)) != null) {
    for (String header : headers) {
      System.out.println(header + " is " + row.get(header));
    }
  }
} finally {
  mapReader.close();
}
```

Writing is quite similar.

Comment: @akapulko: That's not an issue with the CsvMapReader, which can handle an arbitrary number and arrangement of columns.

Comment: thanks for the code sample and the links, going to deep-dive into them :)

Comment: i know this is old, but `inFile` in this example should be `mapReader` and `row.get("header")` should be `row.get(header)` - thanks anyways for this example :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the open source library [**uniVocity-parsers**](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). With this library, not only you can select columns as you want, but also you can select columns in any sequence.

With the following headers:
Name|Number|Color1|Color2......|Color67|

We choose only the columns "Color1", "Color3", and "Color2" from the csv with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // 1st, config the CSV reader
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.selectFields("Color1", "Color3", "Color2");

    // 2nd, creates a CSV parser with the configs
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    // 3rd, parses all rows of data in selected columns from the CSV file into a matrix
    List<String[]> resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("/examples/example.csv"));

    // 3rd, process the matrix with business logic
    for (String[] row : resolvedData) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String col : row) {
            strBuilder.append(col).append("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(strBuilder);
    }
}
```

And you will get output data for these 3 columns:

> red    blue    gray
>   blue   yellow    white

Answer (score 1):

[CsvReader](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv.php) has a [`get()`](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method to read a column by name. The [`CsvWriter`](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvWriter.html) counterpart cannot write to a named column though, so it might only solve half your problem.