# How to pull data from a txt file into a HTML table Java/JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, html-table

I have a Text file (.txt) that contains data strings using comma separated values, i.e

```
jordan,hello,12th Feb 15:23, pending
```

I would like to then pull this data into a HTML table with the ",' separating each column. For example the headings of the table would be:

```
Name   Question   Date    Status
```

Thus Jordan would go in the name column and hello under question etc.

Currently I have output the full string but I need the individual elements.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need a parser to read csv file and create individual elements. You can either use `String.split(...)` or even better leverage [CSV parsing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files). Create a class `Data` and populate it with the parsed data (each row has a corresponding Data object). You should have a `List<Data>` after the entire file has been parsed which you can pass to the JSP page. JSP then iterates through the List and creates the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have a `,` in the data, simply call `split(",")` on each line and create a custom formatted HTML table, something like this (haven't tested):

```
out.println("<table>")

for (int i=0; i<lines.length; ++i) {
    out.println("<tr>" )
    String[] data = line[i].split(",");

    for (String val : data) {
        out.println("<td>" + val + "</td>")
    }

    out.println("</tr>" )
}

out.println("</table>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String#Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to convert your actual String to an array of Strings with all the values:

```
String s = "jordan,hello,12th Feb 15:23, pending"
String[] sArray = s.split(",");
for(String si : sArray) {
    //you can print them in your output
}
```