# Any good library to read and write csv files?

Tags: java, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSV API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)
>   [Can you recommend a Java library for reading (and possibly writing) CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files)

I am wondering if there is a good library that supports reading and writing csv files?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya There is a lot of stuff out there. He is asking for an opinion. There is nothing wrong with that and it is a legitimate question.

Comment: @MarianP unfortunately (I had to learn and accept this too) asking for opinions or recommendations is not very welcome at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 20):

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yup that one works. Only drawback (I found) is that it does not handle file encoding directly and I am unsure if there is a well-known csv-file encoding.

Comment: The file encoding is really not dependent on CSV, it depends mainly on the environment/program where the file is written. So there is not a well established encoding.

Answer (score 20):

I use Apache Commons CSV.
http://commons.apache.org/csv/

There is also Super CSV, but I haven't tried it.
http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/

It is also not such a big deal to write something on your own IMO.

Comment: Well, there are a few cases with quotes and escaping, so it's a little more than meets the eye.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to write your own for something standard, especially when there's multiple libraries available. If you do write your own please take a look at the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend to use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

**What is opencsv?**

> opencsv is a very simple csv (comma-separated values)
>   parser library for Java.