# How can I read comma separated values from a text file in Java?

Tags: java, string, io

I have got this text file with latitude and longitude values of different points on a map.

How can I split my string into latitudes and longitudes? What is the general way to do these type of things that is with other delimiters like space or tab etc.?
Sample file:

```
28.515046280572285,77.38258838653564
28.51430151808072,77.38336086273193
28.513566177802456,77.38413333892822
28.512830832397192,77.38490581512451
28.51208605426073,77.3856782913208
28.511341270865113,77.38645076751709
```

This is the code I am using to read from the file:

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"))) {
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("File Read Error");
}
```

Comment: OpenCSV is a popular library if you would prefer using that. 
Details here: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ There are also a few other stackoverflow questions on a similar topic: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may use the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
```

After that, use [`Double.parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) method to parse the string value to a double.

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
```

Similar parse methods exist in the other wrapper classes as well - `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @user1425223 note that `String.split` takes a regex and if you want to ensure nothing funny happens (like with `.` or `|`) you can first pass the separator through  `Pattern.quote()`: `str.split(Pattern.quote("."))` (or escape it manually)

Comment: @AVD ::  did you get the first line in your text file whcih you have shown above?I am not able to get the content of the first line...rest all is great.

Comment: @user3560140 That code snippet explains the usage of `Split` method. Please ask a new question if you've some issues with your code.

Comment: @AVD:I guess the solution was provided to read the comma seperated values from text file?Which it does not do correctly.While reading it is not reading the first values in that text file.So if someone use this as a example he would run into problems unneccessarily.That was the reason to bring it up through a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use OpenCSV for reliability. Split should never be used for these kind of things.
Here's a snippet from a program of my own, it's pretty straightforward. I check if a delimiter character was specified and use this one if it is, if not I use the default in OpenCSV (a comma). Then i read the header and fields

```
CSVReader reader = null;
try {
    if (delimiter > 0) {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.csvFile), this.delimiter);
    }
    else {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.csvFile));
    }

    // these should be the header fields
    header = reader.readNext();
    while ((fields = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // more code
    }
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To split your String by comma(,) use `str.split(",")` and for tab use `str.split("\\t")`

```
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                               new FileReader("G:\\RoutePPAdvant2.txt"));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] ar=str.split(",");
            ...
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `BigDecimal`, not `double`

The [Answer by adatapost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960224/642706) is right about using `String::split` but wrong about using `double` to represent your longitude-latitude values. The `float`/`Float` and `double`/`Double` types use [floating-point technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) which [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution.

Instead use [`BigDecimal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) to correctly represent your lat-long values.

## Use *Apache Commons CSV* library

Also, best to let a library such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) perform the chore of reading and writing [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [Tab-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) files.

## Example app

Here is a complete example app using that *Commons CSV* library. This app writes then reads a data file. It uses `String::split` for the writing. And the app uses `BigDecimal` objects to represent your lat-long values.

```
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class LatLong
{
    //----------|  Write  |-----------------------------
    public void write ( final Path path )
    {
        List < String > inputs =
                List.of(
                        "28.515046280572285,77.38258838653564" ,
                        "28.51430151808072,77.38336086273193" ,
                        "28.513566177802456,77.38413333892822" ,
                        "28.512830832397192,77.38490581512451" ,
                        "28.51208605426073,77.3856782913208" ,
                        "28.511341270865113,77.38645076751709" );

        // Use try-with-resources syntax to auto-close the `CSVPrinter`.
        try ( final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader( "latitude" , "longitude" ).print( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ; )
        {
            for ( String input : inputs )
            {
                String[] fields = input.split( "," );
                printer.printRecord( fields[ 0 ] , fields[ 1 ] );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //----------|  Read  |-----------------------------
    public void read ( Path path )
    {
        // TODO: Add a check for valid file existing.

        try
        {
            // Read CSV file.
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( path );
            Iterable < CSVRecord > records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse( reader );
            for ( CSVRecord record : records )
            {
                BigDecimal latitude = new BigDecimal( record.get( "latitude" ) );
                BigDecimal longitude = new BigDecimal( record.get( "longitude" ) );
                System.out.println( "lat: " + latitude + " | long: " + longitude );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //----------|  Main  |-----------------------------
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        LatLong app = new LatLong();

        // Write
        Path pathOutput = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/lat-long.csv" );
        app.write( pathOutput );
        System.out.println( "Writing file: " + pathOutput );

        // Read
        Path pathInput = Paths.get( "/Users/basilbourque/lat-long.csv" );
        app.read( pathInput );

        System.out.println( "Done writing & reading lat-long data file. " + Instant.now() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Fourteen decimal places is probably sufficient… https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674

Answer (score 0):

`//lat=3434&lon=yy38&rd=1.0&|` in that format o/p is displaying

```
public class ReadText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream f= new FileInputStream("D:/workplace/sample/bookstore.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
        String strline;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((strline = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] arraylist=StringUtils.split(strline, ",");
            if(arraylist.length == 2){
                sb.append("lat=").append(StringUtils.trim(arraylist[0])).append("&lon=").append(StringUtils.trim(arraylist[1])).append("&rt=1.0&|");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: "+strline);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Data: "+sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the java.util.Scanner class.

```
private static void readFileWithScanner() {
    File file = new File("path/to/your/file/file.txt");

    Scanner scan = null;

    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
            // do something with lineArray, such as instantiate an object
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scan.close();
    }
}
```