# Read comma separated text file within Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner, readfile

My text file is like:

```
1, gold, silver, truck
2, gold, fire, truck
3, china, asia, gold, silver, truck, truck
4, ireland, spain, prague, paris
```

How to jump the first element of the line (1,2,3,4) and read rest of the word one by one?

And how to read only the first element of a row?

Cause I need to store them separatly into two HashMaps.

Thx

Comment: I smell a homework assignment...

Comment: `split()` method on the string object. Also use the `BufferedFileReader` class' `readLine()` method

Comment: use `String.split(",")` and `String.replaceAll("\\w", "")`

Comment: Come on!! it's not very hard. The time your've spent writing your question would have been the time to figure out the answer yourself by googling.

Comment: really you didn't make any google search? I think it's trivial!

Comment: Try searching for your exact title: https://www.google.com/search?q=Read+comma+separated+text+file+within+Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read comma separated values from a text file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960213/how-can-i-read-comma-separated-values-from-a-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You read the file line by line and [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) each line at the commas. This gives you a `String[]`. The first Element in that Array is the number, the others are the words.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You need to read the file line by line, so try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // do stuff
}
br.close();
```

and if you want to skip the first element add this code before the while loop.

```
br.readLine();//to skip the first line
```

Comment: How will the second code snippet help skipping the first element?

Answer (score 0):

you can read file line by line and use string tokenizer:
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(String readline, String ","); Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can read separate the tokens with comma and read token by token:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter(",|$");

int lineNumber = 1;
String lineNumberStr = String.valueof(lineNumber);

while (sc.hasNext()) {

    String token = sc.next();

    if (toekn.equals(lineNumberStr)) {
        ++lineNumber;
        lineNumberStr = String.valueof(lineNumber);
        continue;
    } // if

    putWordIntoMyHashMap(token);
} // while
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at commons-csv? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: I think the simple task the OP wants to implement can be easily done without a library. I feel like that would be overkill.