# how to check and filter for group of different values in java

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have a text file with the data as shown below as an example..

```
2;30;1;801;2;1951;195102;1111;
2;30;1;801;3;1621;162101;1111;
2;30;1;802;1;1807;180702;1111;
2;30;1;802;1;1807;180703;1111;
2;30;1;802;1;1807;180704;1111;
2;30;1;802;2;1101;110101;1111;
2;30;1;802;2;1139;113902;9999;
2;30;1;802;2;1948;194801;1111;
2;30;1;802;2;1948;194802;1111;
2;30;1;802;3;2477;247701;1111;
2;37;2;803;1;2006;200601;0000;
2;37;2;803;1;2006;200602;0000;
2;37;2;803;2;2005;200501 ;0000;
```

In my program I have to put a filter and then display, which groups the  Rows  i.e. `Row[3]` based on  `Row[7]`. My list should appear like this after filtering for example only for 802

```
802;1;1807;180702;1111;
802;1;1807;180703;1111;
802;1;1807;180704;1111;
802;2;1101;110101;1111;
802;2;1139;113902;9999;
802;2;1948;194801;1111;
802;2;1948;194802;1111;
802;3;2477;247701;1111;
```

similarly for 803

```
803;1;2006;200601;0000;
803;1;2006;200602;0000;
803;2;2005;200501 ;0000;
```

The problem is the value of `Row[3]` is not constant and keeps varying throughout the file in a group for example a bunch of values are 802, the next bunch 804, 806 etc and so on. which should be grouped like as shown above. 
I already have a `FileReader` for reading the file, but can anyone tell me a logic on how to go about applying this filter?

code for reading file and placing values in a list

```
public ArrayList<Asset> getData() {

        ArrayList<Asset> list = new ArrayList<Asset>(); 
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            Asset sd = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                 String[] RowData = line.split(";");
                 if (RowData.length >= 19) {
                     sd = new Asset();
                    sd.setProductID(RowData[3]);
                    sd.setProductName(RowData[7]);
                    sd.setStatus(RowData[13]);
                    list.add(sd);
                    }
                }   
                return list;
                }
```

I am confused as to what logic to add in order to filter `RowData[3]` in the `while` loop while reading from the `reader`

Comment: Please include the Java code you have tried and describe what your problem with it is.

Comment: take a look on this question about reading CSV files in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960213/how-to-read-comma-separated-values-from-text-file-in-java

Comment: If the value of `Row[3]` 'cannot be seen until the runtime, it is dynamic and keeps changing' I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to filter the rows for *one* value of `Row[3]`? For which value? How is this value determined? Or do you want to *group* the rows for *all* values of `Row[3]` that occur in the file?

Comment: In other words, how do I group Row[3] which are of identical values other than hardcoding the value and checking for it..

Answer (score 0):

First you filter out the rows with row[3] == 803 (or so) and then you sort based on row[7] like

```
Collections.sort(filteredCsvRowsCollection,new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
   @Override
   public int compare(final Integer[] lhs,final Integer[] rhs) {
         if (lhs[7] > rhs[7]) { return 1; } 
         else if (lhs[7] < rhs[7]) { return -1; }
         else { return 0; }
     }
}
```

Which is adopted from
[How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: But the value for Row[3] cannot be seen until the runtime, it is dynamic and keeps changing. Is there anyway not to hardcode this value of Row[3]

Comment: Sorry, I would not solve this problem in java, but Clojure with clojure.data.csv, the solution would be something like (sort-by #(nth % 7) (filter #(= (nth % 3) 803) (csv/read-csv in-file) as at https://github.com/clojure/data.csv