# Reading .txt information and loading it into an array

Tags: java, file

So, basically, I will have a file called "data.txt"

**This file will contain**:

```
Name;Age;State
```

**Example**:

```
Anne;19;S (Single/Married/etc)
Gustav;18;S
Dinisio;19;C
```

Basically, I want to read the file, put the information into an array, and show/list it, example:

```
Name: Anne
Age: 19
State: S

Name: Gustav
Age: 18
State: S

Name: Dinisio
Age: 19
State: C
```

For that I made a class with the following structure:

```
    class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    char state;
    }
```

Variables:

```
    int i, option;
    String s;
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\data.txt");

    Person arrayPerson[] = new Person[4]; // It has 4 persons only
```

I have the following menu:

```
    System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
    System.out.println("\n1- Load");
    System.out.println("2- List");
    System.out.print("Option: ");
    option= ler.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            Exercicio07Java.openRead(f);
            while((s = Exercicio07Java.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] str = s.split(";");
                arrayPerson[i] = new Person();
                arrayPerson[i].name = str[0];
                arrayPerson[i].age = Integer.valueOf(str[1]);
                arrayPerson[i].state = str[2].charAt(0);
                i++;
            }
            Exercicio07Java.closeRead();
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(arrayPerson[i].nome);
                System.out.println(arrayPerson[i].idade);
                System.out.println(arrayPerson[i].estado);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

I know more or less how to read the information, yet I do not know how to pass it into an array, while it is being separated by ***;***

Any idea?

Comment: Start with looking up String.split(";");

Comment: just google "read comma separated file java" and you will get hundreds of tutorials

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read comma separated values from text file in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960213/how-to-read-comma-separated-values-from-text-file-in-java)

Comment: I've already read that one but didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using String.Split(String delimiter) it returns a String[]. If you read in an entire line as a string and created a new person. See below. This might be a good place to look for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
     String [] info = /**Line From File Here As A String*/.split(";");
     persons[i].name = info[0];
     persons[i].age = info[1];
     persons[i].state = info[2];
}
```

Comment: You'll have to cast info[1] and info[2] to the correct data type too.

Comment: I've edited my post to my actual code, doesn't it work because it is a while? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly asking. But, I think what you have should work swimmingly.

Comment: I found what I needed, I should've added persons[i] = new Person(); inside

Comment: Ah yes my bad yeah your persons[] was not initialized with "dummy" persons. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

So say if you have four lines for example, you could do something like:

```
int index = 0;
while//read line in a file {
    String[] str = lineFromFile.split(";");//will split line on semicolon and you have name in index 0 of array, age in index 1 of str array and so on
    //validate you have all three parameters that you need to create person object.
    Person person = new Person(str[0], convertToInt(str[1]), str[2].charAt(0));//assuming you have constructor that accepts name, converted method to convert age to integer, state
    arrayPerson[index++]=person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bufferedreader for read line and the split with ; marker 
and after this 
set the arrayproperty like 
arrayPerso[i].name = temp[0] //here temp is string array which is generated for split values storage