# How do I convert two different columns from a .csv file to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am trying to create two different arrays from separate columns in a csv file.
The csv file has one column for 'month's' and one column for 'temperatures'. This is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to turn these values into arrays.

```
public class InputOutput
{
    private double temperature;

    public InputOutput()
    {
        List<String> temperatures = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<String> tempIterator = temperatures.iterator();

    }

    public static double getTemp()
    {
        double tempReading = 0.0;
        try
        {
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Downloads\\MNMINPLS.csv";                 //location of MNMINPLS.csv
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);                                               //scanner reads file
            while(scan.hasNext())                           //iterator
            {
                String tempData = scan.next();
                String[] nums = tempData.split(",");
                tempReading = Double.parseDouble(nums[3]);

                System.out.println(tempReading);
            }//end while
            scan.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end try/catch
        return tempReading;
    }//end method getTemp

    public static int getMonth() 
    {
        int m = 0;
        try
        {
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Downloads\\MNMINPLS.csv";                 //location of MNMINPLS.csv
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);                                               //scanner reads file
            while(scan.hasNext())                       //iterator
            {
                String month = scan.next();
                    if(month == month)
                        m++;
                String[] timeOfYear = month.split(",");
                m = Integer.parseInt(timeOfYear[0]);

                System.out.println(m);
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end try/catch
        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want arrays or array lists (seeing as you have an array list for temperatures)? Whenever you don't know how to use a standard Java class, it's a good idea to start by consulting the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You'll find that you can answer your own question most of the time after doing so. HINT: ArrayList has an .add() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
temperatures.add(Double.toString(tempReading));
```

Just add the value to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have `<date>,temp` rows like this:

```
4,12,2014,70.3 //12 Apr 2014 weather
5,1,2014,74.5 //1 May 2014 weather
6,27,2014,85.8 //27 June 2014 weather
```

And what you want in the end is an int array `monthsArr` with the value `{4, 5, 6}`, plus a parallel double array `tempsArr` with the value `{70.3, 74.5, 85.8}`

First, make your `temperatures` ArrayList a member of the class (move it up to where `private double temperature` is), and add an additional `months` ArrayList. **Make temperatures an `ArrayList<Double>` and months an `ArrayList<Integer>`**

Then, you can add the parsed value to the appropriate ArrayList using the `add()` method.

Finally, when done parsing, the easiest way to convert to an Array is to use the `toArray()` method like so:

```
double[] tempsArr = temperatures.toArray(new double[]);
int[] monthsArr = months.toArray(new int[]);
```

The `ArrayList<E>` API spec (Java SE7) is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to read your file only once

```
double[] temperatures=new double[maxsize];
 String[] months=new String[maxsize];
 int index=0;
    while(scan.hasNext())                           //iterator
            {
                String tempData = scan.next();
                String[] nums = tempData.split(",");
                tempReading = Double.parseDouble(nums[3]);
                monthReading = nums[2]; //or whichever index
                temperatures[index]=tempReading;
                months[index]=monthReading;
                index++
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I read and parse a CSV file? I would use third party CSV reader say CSV reader. The "why not write own CSV parser" list can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950812/1737819). Hope this will help :) :

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                        new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Downloads\\MNMINPLS.csv"));
String [] nextLine;

// If you want lists
List<Integer> months       = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Double>  temperatures = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (null != (nextLine = reader.readNext())) 
{
    months.add(
                Integer.valueOf(nextLine[0]));
    temperatures.add(
                Double.valueOf(nextLine[1]));
}

// or if you want your data as an array see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])
Integer[] monthsArr = months.toArray(new Integer[0]);
Double[]  tempsArr  = temperatures.toArray(new Double[0]);
```