# Giving input to Java through a batch file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing an application in which users give an input in the batch file and that batch file input be given as an input to eclipse and oy will run a Java program(logic) and give the output either through a batch file or an excel.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: please give example of input and expected output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Read CSV with Scanner()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274259/java-read-csv-with-scanner)

Comment: Input is a few parameters for a functionality. For example, while dealing with ports, portId is an input. Inputs are fine. I just need to know how do I make eclipse read those inputs that are given in the batch file.

Comment: Decide either you run your program just using command line or set Run Configurations, command args in Eclipse. Your are mixing 2 things i.e. trying to do something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse you can set arguments using Run > Run Configurations > Arguments

Running the jar file directly works just as simple: `java -jar someFile.jar port ip whatever else`

Those arguments will be passed to the `main()` method as a `String[]`, so if you want numbers you will have to convert them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(args[0]); // port
        System.out.println(args[1]); // ip
        System.out.println(args[2]); // whatever
        System.out.println(args[3]); // else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the batch file you'll have something like this:

```
echo off
java -jar MyJavaJar.jar %1 %2 %*
```

Where %1 is the first parameter, %2 the second and %* anything else...

In your java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Check if args were supplied, e.g. args.length
    //else out put usage information
}
```

Hope this helps