# Reading data from a CSV file using scanner throws exception

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I just started using Java recently so please bear with me. I'm trying to create an array of the object Product by reading data from a csv file with the format

`Name,Price,Stock`

but every time I'm trying using the `Load()` function it keeps giving me an error in the Product constructor line.

```
  private Product[] product = new Product[100];

  public Product[] Load() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int  counter = 0;
    boolean end = false;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("products.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    while (!end) {
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            product[counter] = new Product(scanner.next(), scanner.nextFloat(), scanner.nextInt());
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            end = true;
        }

    }

    scanner.close();
    return product;
}
```

the error message is `java.util.scanner.next(unknown source)`, and the same error for both **scanner.nextFloat()** and **scanner.nextInt()**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at ScoutShop.CSVReader.Load(CSVReader.java:20)
at ScoutShop.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: Surely that can't be the *entire* error.

Comment: You should post entire stack trace of the thrown exception.

Comment: i added the whole error at the end

Comment: You're testing `scanner.hasNext()`, and then you do three `scanner.next()`.

Comment: if the scanner.hasNext() is true then there will always be the name price and stock in that specific order

Answer (score 0):

The generated java class should also be the same location of products.csv.

Or try to put the products.csv in the root or in `C:\products.csv and do (and see what happens):

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\products.csv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for the `new File(String path)` knowing that you must specify the exact file path for the file you are trying to read

check this answer for CSV parsing [CSV Parsing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950812/8279593) by [Scheintod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1455622/scheintod)

```
private Product[] product = new Product[100];
public Product[] load() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int  counter = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("products.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    // try the following while loop without use of if-else statements to 
    // avoid complexity in case of up scaling/maintaining your application 
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
         // System.out.print(scanner.next()+"|");
         product[counter] = new Product(scanner.next(), scanner.nextFloat(), 
         scanner.nextInt());
         counter++;
    }
    scanner.close();
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Did you specify full path?

Comment: Yes i added the full path and removed the if conditioning but the same error pops up at the same line of code

Comment: Attach the whole file please and i will test it on my machine, and show me the full path of the file