# Mapping String with delimiters to list of strings or to new object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a file with some data separated by semicolon. I'm trying to build a stream, which will read file line by line, separate every column of data and map it to new object.

data.txt:

```
John;Smith;42;shopassistant
Clara;Lefleur;24;programmer
```

Person.class:

```
public class Person{
   String name;
   String lastName;
   int age;
   String job;
}
```

I started with something like this:

```
List<Person> people = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/data.txt"))....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read CSV with Scanner()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274259/read-csv-with-scanner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Scanner` would be more useful for this job, and since `java-9` this is much nicer to work with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+);(\\w+);(\\w+);(\\w+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
List<Person> persons = new Scanner(Paths.get("src/data.txt"))
            .findAll(p)
            .map(mr -> new Person(mr.group(1), mr.group(2), Integer.valueOf(mr.group(3)), mr.group(4)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is it more compliant to standards?

Comment: @steve1337 what do you mean?

Comment: Which solution would you be pleased to see during, let’s say, code review?

Comment: @steve1337 obviously this. A `Scanner` *is* the tool for this to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

You can use map like so :

```
List<Person> people = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/data.txt"))
        .map(p -> p.split(";"))//split each line with ';'
        .map(p -> new Person(p[0], p[1], Integer.valueOf(p[2]), p[3]))//create a new Person
        .collect(Collectors.toList());//then collect the result
```

Make sure that you have a constructor which hold that information :

```
public Person(String name, String lastName, int age, String job) {
```

Comment: Great solution. I didn't know how stream behaves after .map method and didn't find out that I could use it twice. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome @steve1337, because map return a `Stream<R>` so you can use another map, and so on

Comment: @YCF_L [FYI this can be done nicer with java-9 and Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017044/1059372)

Comment: @Eugene yes If the user use Java-9+ but I like to use `Files` as I can use `takeWhile`, `dropWhile` and many other better tools +1 any way

Comment: @YCF_L and btw you got lucky here with a single char regex, otherwise that `Pattern` should have been taken outside the stream per-se...

Comment: @Eugene I test both code mine and yours I found that my code is more quick, you can check that in your own environment

Comment: @YCF_L *test both code mine and yours I found that my code is more quick*, sorry but that is like saying nothing, proper tests and proper explanation of them is a lot harder than me and you might think