# migrate csv to Firestore

Tags: firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore, migrate

I am having trouble finding a solution that solves my problem of migrating my CSV data to Firebase Cloud Firestore, as my research found alternatives and I performed them but I was unsuccessful in importing the data.

I can't find a way that currently works so that I can migrate the data from my CSV file to Cloud Firestore.

### Does anyone know a way to migrate?

Comment: What I did before was writing a script to read the data from the CSV and then upload it to Firestore using the java admin sdk.

Comment: @YayoArellano Sounds like an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no one button solution for this. I do not have the code now but I will tell the steps how I did it using Java.

1 - First read the data from the CSV. Check this Stackoverflow answer [How to CSV with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274319/3479489)

2 - Using the [Firebase Java Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) you can upload the data to Firestore.

Comment: Okay, I know this way but I will use document write quotas to migrate the data which I don't think is right, but from what I saw is the only way.