# Import .csv to RTC using JAVA

Tags: java, rtc

I am working on IBM RTC and I need to import a .csv file to RTC **using JAVA**. Is there a way to do this? If yes, can someone help me with the same.

Comment: For the record: most likely, you will not see any other input to your question. So, just for the record: if you found my answer to be helpful, consider accepting it (clicking that check mark icon next to the answer). Will help your and my reputation count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing CSV data is something that you **definitely** do not want to implement yourself, there are plenty of libraries for that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files)).

RTC offers a wide range of APIs that can be used with, see:

1. [rsjazz.wordpress.com](https://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/what-apis-are-available-for-rtc-and-what-can-you-extend/) or
2. [jazz.net](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229)

In that sense: you can write Java code that reads CSV data, and RTC has a rich API that allows you push "content" into the system.

But a word of **warning**: I used that java API some years ago to manipulate information within our RTC instance. That was a very **painful** experience. I found the APIs to be badly documented and extremely hard to use. It took me several days to come to working code that would make just a few small updates to our stories/tasks.

Maybe things have improved since then, but be prepared for, as said ... a painful experience.

EDIT, regarding your comment on "other options":

Well, I dont see them: you want to push data you have in CSV into your RTC instance. So, if you still want to do that, you have to use that means that are available to you! And don't let my words discourage you. A) it was some time back when I did my programming with RTC, so maybe their APIs are better structured and more intuitive today. B) there is some documentation out there (for example [here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/131121/programmatic-creation-of-work-items-guide-for-rtc-40x)). And I think everybody can register at jazz.net; so when you have further, specific questions, you might find "better" answers there!

All I wanted to say was: I know that other products such as jenkins or sonarqube have **great** APIs; and you work with that, all nice, easy, fun. You get things working with RTC, too. Just the path there, maybe isnt that nice and easy.

My personal recommendation: start with the RTC part first. Meaning: just try to write a small programm that authenticates against the server; and then push some example data into the system. If that works nicely for you; then spend the time on pulling / transforming the real data that you have in mind!

Comment: thanks for a quick response. But as you said about 'a painful experience', could you suggest another way of doing what I want to?

Comment: See my updated answer ... again, as I made more updates ;-) ... but please understand that I can't say much more ... I already "invested" quite some time here; and so far, not a single upvote ;-|