# Java Read a file and create an object for each corresponding row

Tags: java, list, object

I have a CSV file that I am reading from. I have created a constructor with six arguments for initialising the six fields and a public string method to convert a string into the format I need.

```
public Hill(int number, String name, String countyName, double height, double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.countyName = countyName;
    this.height = height;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is after opening the file and reading it, it creates the corresponding object and then to return the list of the items.

I was given an inital method of `public static List<Hill> readHills()`

I have commented out a line which i tried to create a new object from simply because I wasn't sure if I was doing it right, so i just printed out as a test to see what my code was doing and it seems that the new object line is redundant.
Currently my code is:

```
public static List<Hill> readHills() {
    Scanner fileName = null;
    try {
        fileName = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/TOSHIBA/Desktop/hills.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Scanner finalFileName = fileName;
    List<Hill> list = new ArrayList<Hill>() {
        {
                for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
                    String line = finalFileName.nextLine();
                    String[] splitted = line.split(",");
                    //add(new Hill(1, "", "", 100, 100, 100));
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
                }

            }
    };
    return list;
}
```

In the code where I create the object I put a sample value but technically I want the 6 fields of the new object to be from the file I read. If i try adding the field names, i get a red line saying `Non static method cannot be referenced from a static method`

Where am i going wrong? And why is my line of code useless?

I continued trying to play with the code but can't get anywhere, I think my issue is not understand the method name i have been given; i.e. Why and what does `public static List<Hill> readHills()` do?

I tried using `Hill newHill = new Hill( int number, String name, String countyName,double height, double latitude, double longitude);` but can't since I cant reference a non-static field from a static context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters: this here

```
List<Hill> list = new ArrayList<Hill>() {
```

is valid syntax, but **not at all** what you want.

Just go for:

```
List<Hill> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead. What you are doing creates an anonymous inner class; and that is totally not required here; and instead leading to many of the issues you see.

Then: you have to turn your strings into the correct type:

```
 String[] splitted = line.split(",");
```

gives you an array of **String** objects. You have to convert those; so that you can pass them to the constructor accordingly (your constructor expects an **int** value as first parameter, not a **String** for example!)

```
Hill hill = new Hill(Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]), splitted[1], ...
```

and so on.

And then you do:

```
list.add(hill);
```

But the tricky part is: such *parsing* relies on "correct" input. So you should be prepared for all kinds of error handling.

And beyond that: unless this is homework, then do **not** implement your own CSV parser. Use some existing library for that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files) for ideas). You see: doing **correct** CSV parsing, that works with all the subtle quirks of this format is **not** easy. You can easily spend hours on this task; to then find that the next CSV file you work with ... contains yet another (valid!) variation of CSV input that breaks your self-written parser. (believe me, I have been there)

And finally: if such things already overburden you, then the real takeaway is: accept that you are not there yet. Step back; get back into learning mode and understand all those basic Java things.

Comment: I see, but since i start of my code like `List<Hill> list = new ArrayList<Hill>() {` my list isnt initialized. So should i rewrite my code in a different format? Because i would've though my list is initialised.

Comment: See my updates; I just realized that you have a *gross* syntax mistake in your code which causes most of your trouble.

Comment: Yes, and another downvote. Please speak up. I have no idea why you think this answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: Hmm, Since my CSV has a row which corresponds to what the remaining rows it has, For example "Number" which is a string, but starting from the 2nd row, they correspond to the actual types we define i.e. as an Int it will get an error. So that means i have to start from the second row?

Comment: For example. As said: there are **many** subtle things that make csv parsing hard. Column headers are one of them.

Comment: Would a workaround be, using a for loop to start at 1 uptil the length of how many rows there are?. Because I changed my code a bit, removing the for loop and adding a while loop to go through each line (using `while fileName.hasNextLine`

Comment: I also noticed that since some of my values are doubles, the code needs to be `Double.parseDouble`.