# how to set background colour reading from a csv file from an array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

The problem is reading back an r,g,b and setting the r,g,b into a setBackground colour when reading from a csv file (comma separated values file) but the csv file also has text in it that needs to be set to the text fields.

the save button saves the file into a csv format that then needs to be read back into the fields which is just a 2d array of text fields.

```
public void writeDataFile(String fileName)
{
    try
    {

        BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("e:\\EmissionsTracker.csv"));
        for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < totalY ; y++)
            {
                outFile.write(fields[0][y].getText() + "," + fields[x][0].getText() + "," + fields[x][y].getText() + ",");
                outFile.write(fields[x][y].getBackground() + ",");



                outFile.newLine();
            }
        }
        outFile.close();

    }
 public void saveEmmisionsTableToFile(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++)
            {
                outFile.write(fields[x][y].getBackground() + "," );               
            }

            outFile.newLine();
        }
        outFile.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void readDataFile(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++)
            {
                String temp[] = br.readLine().split(","); 
                fields[x][y].setText(temp[5]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());            
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < totalY ; y++)
            {
                outFile.write(fields[0][y].getText() + "," + fields[x][0].getText() + "," + fields[x][y].getText() + ",");
                outFile.write(fields[x][y].getBackground().getRed() + "," + fields[x][y].getBackground().getGreen() + "," + fields[x][y].getBackground().getBlue() + ",");
                outFile.newLine();
            }
        }
for (int x = 0; x < totalX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < totalY; y++)
            {

                String temp[] = br.readLine().split(","); 
                fields[x][y].setText(temp[2]);

                fields[x][y].setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(temp[3]),Integer.parseInt(temp[4]),Integer.parseInt(temp[5])));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

CSV files that contain commas in their values should start and end with double quotes. This statement from [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) summarises it well:

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>
>    zzz,yyy,xxx

Any half-decent CSV parsing library will take care of this for you automatically.

See also [So You Want To Write Your Own CSV code?](http://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137343/java-csv-parser-comparisons) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions which contain Java CSV library recommendations

Comment: the first line from the csv file when reading reads this 
javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255
this is the whole line
14,1,14,javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255]

Comment: ...so the row should actually look like `14,1,14,"javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=255,g=255,b=255]"` otherwise it's not really a CSV file

Comment: Or instead of writing out a string representation of `ColorUIResource`, why not just write out the red, green and blue values as separate CSV columns? Seems like you're making your life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: no but i dont want the javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource cause then i cant read the data back and set the colour and that line of code is gotten via a method of getBackground() which is from a library

Comment: Assuming that `getBackground()` returns a `ColorUIResource`, just use `getBackground().getGreen()`, `getBackground().getBlue()`, etc.? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ColorUIResource.html

Comment: ah i see that does fix it didnt know that existed thank you

Comment: is there a way to return the colour name? or would i just have to check what the numbers are and set something to the be the colour name if the number match that format

Comment: I would assume that whatever library you're using would also have a `setBackground()` method also? Use the API link I posted to construct a new ColorUIResource based on the separate RGB values you've read in.