# How to read key=value file and how to split a comma-separated String?

Tags: java

I made a config file it has some following format

```
variableName = value
variableName = value
variableName = value
```

I know I can read file split them store them in variable. But I am looking for an easy way. For example I want to store variable names and its value in a file and I want when I read file it automatically restore variables and its values. ( I know how to do it in php and it is very easy but I am not java expert :( )

My second question is about following file read. I have a file that has rows and colums
it can be CSV, for example

```
one,two,three
four,five,six
seven,eight,nine
```

I want to read it that it return whole column for example ( one four seven ) same for others. I don't want to use OpenCSV as its not csv oriented application just for one function.

EDITED:

---

Is it possible to write all variable name and its value and when I read file it automatically declare those variable and assign values?

Comment: You should ask your two questions as two questions posted separately :)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep in mind. But I thought both questions are inter related so I can ask at the same time

Comment: about the last question: you can assign values to the variables in the class by using reflection, not sure about declaring new variables dynamically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to read in the `key=value` file. [Here is a Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

As for the CSV, you can read in all the lines and use [`String#split()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break each line into an array of values.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any other way for CSV? 
For key=value please explain little bit more if you can point any tutorial, related to this thing please send me link

is it possible to save variables and values and restore them?

Comment: Thanks, It helped me for first question. But for CSV. I can split it first in lines then each line in array with for loops and split. But don't you think it is efficient way to do it?? That's why I asked if you can recommend any other way like you recommended properties :)

Comment: Why is it inefficient? Is it because you need to write a loop? Uh well, have you benchmarked it? After all, there is no magic. There is just code. And you write it.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, Yeah, I like to write code. But some time I write long code and I come to know that there is one simple function in java :)
anyways, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be happy that there's `String#split()`, else you would hassle in more lines with `String#substring()`, `String#indexOf()`, `StringTokenizer`, `Scanner`, etc..etc..

Comment: This will not work for parsing a CSV file, which can have quoted values containing commas.

Comment: @Software Monkey: The OP already disclaimered that it's not a real CSV file. Just a *comma separated format*. If one would be interested, here's a basic example how you should parse CSV in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241915/regarding-java-string-manipulation/2241950#2241950

Answer (score 5):

The [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class will load your config file in the name=value format. Call the load method with a [FileReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) to the config file. The you can access any variable using the getProperty method.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileReader(configFilePath));

String value = props.getProperty("name");
```

As for the CSV file, if all rows have the same number of values, you can read each line into an array using String.split(",") and assign it to a 2-d array. Then access a "column" by walking the 2-d array.

Comment: Don't use relative paths in Java IO stuff. It's receipt for trouble. Either use absolute paths, or -the usual way- just put file in classpath and use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: GREAT ! ! !
any suggestion for CSV??

Comment: @BalusC I agree. Removed bad example.

Answer (score 1):

- 1 question: check [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization)
- 2 question: Please see this source code:

  ```
  class RowReader {
  private String path;
  private String columnSeparator;
  private List<String[]> rows;
  private int columnCount;
  public RowReader(String path, String columnSeparator) {
      this.path = path;
      this.columnSeparator = columnSeparator;
      this.rows = getRows();
      if (this.rows == null || this.rows.size() == 0)
          this.columnCount = 0;
      else
          this.columnCount = this.rows.get(0).length;
  }

  public List<String> getColumn(int i) {
      List<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String[] row : rows) {
          column.add(row[i]);
      }
      return column;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
      return columnCount;
  }

  private List<String[]> getRows() {
      List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
      try {
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String line = null;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              rows.add(line.split(columnSeparator));
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return rows;
  }}
  ```

Test class:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RowReader reader = new RowReader("j:\\test.txt", ",");
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            List<String> column = reader.getColumn(i);
            for (String c : column)
                System.out.print(c + ", ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } 
}
```

Console output:

```
one, four, seven, 
two, five, eight, 
three, six, nine,
```

Comment: WOW ! ! !
you wrote whole code right now ????? 
it helped me to alot. Thanks alot.

Comment: This will not work for parsing a CSV file, which can have quoted values containing commas.

Comment: Software Monkey, Thanks for the comments. But I think he was trying to give me a good idea so it worked. I got idea. I can implement it :)

Comment: I am glad that I could help.This is just an idea how to do it. I believe that you are able to correct all bugs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading in everything and using a regular expression splitting the list in to a 2-d array.

Comment: This will not work for parsing a CSV file, which can have quoted values containing commas.