# RegEx - Java Split Command Parsing Csv File

Tags: java, regex, csv, split

I have a CSV in this below format

```
11000,Christopher,Nolan,MR.,Inception,25993,France,"Lefoullon,Paris",920,Director,*461-7755,33-461-7755,12175,"O'Horner, James",12300,"Glebova, Nathalie",,Christophe.Nolan@movies.com,Capital,NEW
```

[Regarding Java Split Command Parsing Csv File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241758/regarding-java-split-command-parsing-csv-file)

In this link @Mark Byers and @R. Bemrose suggested `String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);` But if you notice carefully in the above CSV, you will find a name with `"O'Horner, James"` is causing problems and its throwing `ORA-0917: missing comma` error. Is there a way to avoid it or the reg-ex has to be corrected?

Kinda confused :-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: all of the following is idle speculation and guesswork, as you haven't supplied any code for verification, and my palantir is in the workshop for preventative maintenance.

Train of thought: You don't get a problem with the earlier `"Lefoullon,Paris"` but you do get a problem with `"O'Horner, James"` ... this suggests that the apostrophe is probably the (innocent) cause of the problem.

Hypothesis: The field is successfully extracted from the CSV as `O'Horner, James` ... note that apostrophe is NOT special to CSV (and doesn't occur in that magnificent [see note] regex).

However **the apostrophe is significant to SQL; apostrophes quote string literals in SQL, and apostrophes in the data must be doubled.**

Like this: `INSERT INTO ..... VALUES(...,'O''Horner, James', ...);`

If you are using parameter substitution in your SQL interface (as you should be), converting your data fields into valid SQL constants will be done for you. Otherwise

- write code to fix each string field (replace every occurrence of `'` by `''` then wrap the result in `'` front and back)
- google("SQL injection"), read, repent, and rewrite your code using parameter substitution

---

Note: "magnificent" as in "C'est magnifique, mais ce n'est pas la guerre". Use a CSV parser, for sanity's sake.