# Splitting at space if not between quotes

Tags: java, regex

i tried this:

```
 +|(?!(\"[^"]*\"))
```

but it didn't work.
what can i else do to make it work?
btw im using java's string.split().

Comment: I've answered (almost) the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes Its for C# there, but the solution should work for java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ ]+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

which will split on one or more spaces only if those spaces are followed by zero, or an even number of quotes (all the way to the end of the string!).

The following demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "a \"b c d\" e \"f g\" h";
        System.out.println("text = " + text + "\n");
        for(String t : text.split("[ ]+(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
text = a "b c d" e "f g" h

a
"b c d"
e
"f g"
h
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
var str="Hi there"
var splitOutput=str.split(" ");

//splitOutput[0]=Hi
//splitOutput[1]=there
```

Sorry I misunderstood your question
add this from **Bart's** explanation `\s(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` or `[ ]+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
input.split("(?<!\") (?!\")")
```

Comment: I guess the OP also wants to see if spaces in quotes like these: `"text more text"` (two spaces in there)

Comment: it does not work, the out put i want is: "hi there \"hi there\"" -> ["hi","there","hi there"]